# docker compose not setting environment variables

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i have read a lot of answers on here, i'm still not getting whats going on with my instances

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    build: ./puller-api/
    ports:
    - "8000:8000"
    #restart: "always"
    env_file: 
      - ./env/env-dev.env
    depends_on:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.2
    restart: always
    env_file: 
      - ./env/env-dev.env
```

dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /api
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends apt-utils dialog 2>&1 \
    #
    # Verify git, process tools, lsb-release (common in install instructions for CLIs) installed
    && apt-get -y install git iproute2 procps lsb-release \
    # Clean up
    && apt-get autoremove -y \
    && apt-get clean -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
    COPY . .
    RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
    RUN cd src \
    RUN pip install -e . \
    ENTRYPOINT ["uvicorn", "puller.main:app"]
```

./env/env-dev.env

```
MONGO_DB=puller
MONGO_COL_JOBS=jobs
MONGO_COL_USERS=users
MONGO_CON=mongodb://....
```

then when i run this command:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash puller_api -c env

HOSTNAME=f9e7cd5d2059
PYTHON_VERSION=3.8.2
PWD=/api
HOME=/root
LANG=C.UTF-8
GPG_KEY=E3FF2839C048B25C084DEBE9B26995E310250568
TERM=xterm
SHLVL=0
PYTHON_PIP_VERSION=20.0.2
PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256=421ac1d44c0cf9730a088e337867d974b91bdce4ea2636099275071878cc189e
PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL=https://github.com/pypa/get-pip/raw/d59197a3c169cef378a22428a3fa99d33e080a5d/get-pip.py
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
_=/usr/bin/env
```

as you can see no MONGO env vars are getting set?

docker-compose up -d

then i attach to it with: `docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash puller_api`

and run manually:

```
root@2f5356b25861:/api/src# uvicorn puller.main:app
```

you can see its the MONGO_ vars aren't getting set:

```
User's Environment variable:
{'GPG_KEY': 'E3FF2839C048B25C084DEBE9B26995E310250568',
 'HOME': '/root',
 'HOSTNAME': '2f5356b25861',
 'LANG': 'C.UTF-8',
 'OLDPWD': '/api',
 'PATH': '/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin',
 'PWD': '/api/src',
 'PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256': '421ac1d44c0cf9730a088e337867d974b91bdce4ea2636099275071878cc189e',
 'PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL': 'https://github.com/pypa/get-pip/raw/d59197a3c169cef378a22428a3fa99d33e080a5d/get-pip.py',
 'PYTHON_PIP_VERSION': '20.0.2',
 'PYTHON_VERSION': '3.8.2',
 'SHLVL': '1',
 'TERM': 'xterm',
 '_': '/usr/local/bin/uvicorn'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/uvicorn", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 331, in main
    run(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 354, in run
    server.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 382, in run
    loop.run_until_complete(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
  File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1456, in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_until_complete
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 389, in serve
    config.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 288, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 20, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "./puller/main.py", line 13, in <module>
    from puller.db import dbjobs, dbusers
  File "./puller/db.py", line 17, in <module>
    db = client[os.getenv('MONGO_DB')]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1566, in __getitem__
    return database.Database(self, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 107, in __init__
    raise TypeError("name must be an instance "
TypeError: name must be an instance of str
```

db.py

```
import pymongo
import os
import pprint 

# Get the list of user's 
# environment variables 
env_var = os.environ 

# Print the list of user's 
# environment variables 
print("User's Environment variable:") 
pprint.pprint(dict(env_var), width = 1) 

client = pymongo.MongoClient(os.getenv('MONGO_CON'))
db = client[os.getenv('MONGO_DB')]

dbjobs = db[os.getenv('MONGO_COL_JOBS')]
dbusers = db[os.getenv('MONGO_COL_USERS')]
```

Comment: Have you tried docker-compose down -v to clean up and docker-compose up -d to bring everything back again?

Comment: good suggestion @NguyenLamPhuc , i did do that then a `docker system prune -a` and after the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docker run` doesn't know anything about the Docker Compose setup; values you specify in your `docker-compose.yml` file or a `.env` file won't be considered.

Docker Compose has its own [run](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/) subcommand that *does* know about these things, so if you

```
docker-compose run --entrypoint /bin/env api
```

it will start up the container with all of the settings in the `docker-compose.yml` file (except `ports:`) and run the alternate command.

(Needing `--entrypoint` for this commands is an unnecessary inconvenience; if you change `ENTRYPOINT` to `CMD` in your Dockerfile, you can use the "normal" command part of `docker{,-compose} run` instead of needing to override the entrypoint part.)